# How to copy PIXI's view into another canvas

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

In theory it should be as easy as :

```js
//targetCanvas is a canvas node
//app is instance of PIXI.Application
targetCanvas.drawImage(app.view, 0, 0);
```

But, trust me, It doesn't work!

Sometime (yes, I said sometime) it does work if I add some delay before copying the image into the `targetCanvas`. ... So, I wonder if there is an asynchronous process happening when PIXI is rendering... but I can not find this information in PIXI's documentation.

```js
var loadImage = async function(imgPath) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.onload = ()=> {
            resolve(img);
        }
        img.src = imgPath;
    })
}



var canvasTag = document.querySelector("#canvasVideo");
var canvasCtx = canvasTag.getContext("2d");

var canvasResult = document.querySelector("#canvasResult");
var canvasResultCtx = canvasResult.getContext("2d");

var canvasWidth = canvasTag.width;
var canvasHeight = canvasTag.height;


var canvasWidth = 320;
var canvasHeight = 240;
const app = new PIXI.Application({
    view: document.querySelector("#glCanvas"),
    transparent: true,
    width: canvasWidth,
    height: canvasHeight
});

const container = new PIXI.Container();
const renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer();
app.stage.addChild(container);

(async ()=> {
    var imgTag = await loadImage("data:image/png;base64,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");
    canvasCtx.drawImage(imgTag, 0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

    var bgSprite = PIXI.Sprite.from(imgTag);

    app.stage.addChild(bgSprite);

    canvasResultCtx.drawImage(document.querySelector("#glCanvas"), 0, 0);
})()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://pixijs.download/release/pixi.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvasVideo" width="320" height="240" autoplay></canvas>
    <canvas id="glCanvas" width="320" height="240" autoplay></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvasResult" width="320" height="240" autoplay></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

`canvasVideo` (left) is normal canvas with 2d context.
`glCanvas` (middle) is a PIXI's view
`canvasResult` (right) is a normal canvas where a PIXI view should be copied into.

We don't have any problem copying canvas into PIXI. (except the CORS prevents the webGL renders the image correctly)
But, as you can see, the third canvas is blank. I wonder if there is any solution to this issue... without using PIXI's ticker or setTimeout?

Answer (score 2):

The ticker is not used for non-animated sprites, but apparently pixi still needs ONE frame to draw everything before you can copy it.

I was able to solve your issue with one `requestAnimationFrame`

```js
(async ()=> {
    var imgTag = await loadImage("data:image/png;base64,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");
    canvasCtx.drawImage(imgTag, 0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

    var bgSprite = PIXI.Sprite.from(imgTag);
    app.stage.addChild(bgSprite);

    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        canvasResultCtx.drawImage(document.querySelector("#glCanvas"), 0, 0);
    });
})()
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use the PIXI ticker or a custom timer (requestAnimationFrame as in your own response) to render to the canvas. There's the possibility to simply call `app.render()` in a synchronous way after the desired elements are added to the stage.

On top of that, if you want to prevent having a running application that renders on each frame, you may want to add `autoStart: false` to your Application config.

```js
var loadImage = async function(imgPath) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.onload = ()=> {
            resolve(img);
        }
        img.src = imgPath;
    })
}

var canvasWidth = 320;
var canvasHeight = 240;
const app = new PIXI.Application({
    view: document.querySelector("#glCanvas"),
    transparent: true,
    width: canvasWidth,
    height: canvasHeight,
    autoStart: false,
});

(async () => {
    var imgTag = await loadImage("data:image/png;base64,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");
    var bgSprite = PIXI.Sprite.from(imgTag);

    app.stage.addChild(bgSprite);

    app.render();
})()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://pixijs.download/release/pixi.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="glCanvas" width="320" height="240"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```